# xcode: Thread 1: Signal SIGABART in class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate (game application)

Tags: ios, swift

Before marking as duplicate, please consider that I have searched the web and StackOverflow but I didn't find any solution for this specific problem (because all questions about this error are for apps, not games).

I am making a very basic Space Shooter game and I reached a stage where I want to make the hero (code below) shoot bullets; I created a function spawn_bullet to do this. After I wrote this function and called it in the function:

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval),

I get the error: **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**. Image is shown below

[image]
I believe that the error has something to do with the execution of the spawn_bullet function but I am not sure where it is, why it caused and how to fix it. Anyone has an idea to fix it and if possible to provide enough details for why it causes?

Thank you!

**NOTE**
English is not my first language (that's why it's bad)

Below I provide my code used in GameScene.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero")
    var bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
    var enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
    var init_bullet_position = CGFloat(0)
    var bullet_velocityY = CGFloat(5)

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.7, green: 0.7, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)

        self.hero.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0)
        self.hero.size.height = 50
        self.hero.size.width = 30
        self.hero.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + self.hero.size.height)

        self.bullet.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0)
        self.bullet.size.height = 30
        self.bullet.size.width = 15
        self.bullet.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + self.hero.size.height + self.hero.size.height / 4)

        self.init_bullet_position = CGFloat(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + self.hero.size.height + self.hero.size.height / 4)

        self.hero.zPosition = 1;    //1 = front
        self.addChild(bullet)
        self.addChild(hero)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode!(self)
            hero.position.x = location.x
            if self.bullet.position.y == init_bullet_position{
                self.bullet.position.x = location.x
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode!(self)
            self.hero.position.x = location.x
            if self.bullet.position.y == init_bullet_position{
                self.bullet.position.x = location.x
            }
        }
    }

    func spawn_bullets(){
        self.bullet.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0)
        self.bullet.size.height = 30
        self.bullet.size.width = 15
        self.bullet.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + self.hero.size.height + self.hero.size.height / 4)
        self.addChild(bullet)

        if self.bullet.position.y < self.frame.size.height{
            self.bullet.position.y += self.bullet_velocityY
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        spawn_bullets()
    }
}
```

Here is the exception message:

```
2016-07-14 23:07:54.564 Space shooter[14391:191912] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'bullet' (400 x 600)] position:{160, 62.5} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{15, 30} anchor:{0.5, 0} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec4fd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111299deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec4fcbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   SpriteKit                           0x000000010fb74903 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 162
    4   SpriteKit                           0x000000010fb74840 -[SKNode addChild:] + 68
    5   Space shooter                       0x000000010ea62d23 _TFC13Space_shooter9GameScene13spawn_bulletsfT_T_ + 995
    6   Space shooter                       0x000000010ea62ef4 _TFC13Space_shooter9GameScene6updatefSdT_ + 36
    7   Space shooter                       0x000000010ea62f2c _TToFC13Space_shooter9GameScene6updatefSdT_ + 44
    8   SpriteKit                           0x000000010fb48072 -[SKScene _update:] + 312
    9   SpriteKit                           0x000000010fb6503a -[SKView _update:] + 932
    10  SpriteKit                           0x000000010fb6221a __59-[SKView _renderSynchronouslyForTime:preRender:postRender:]_block_invoke + 170
    11  SpriteKit                           0x000000010fb620e8 -[SKView _renderSynchronouslyForTime:preRender:postRender:] + 235
    12  SpriteKit                           0x000000010fb64ac2 -[SKView layoutSubviews] + 85
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010fdd8980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    14  QuartzCore                          0x00000001151d7c00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001151cc08e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001151cbf0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001151c03c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    18  QuartzCore                          0x00000001151ee086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00000001151ee7f8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eb74c37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eb74ba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eb6a11c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010fd18f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010fd1df09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    25  Space shooter                       0x000000010ea64e82 main + 114
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111dc792d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the stack trace + exception message that got printed to the console

Comment: Please also show your code.

Comment: Sorry guys for the missing parts. I successfully updated my question.

Comment: When debugging crashes, I suggest taking a look at the debug log. It may be intimidating, but certain parts help you, such as 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:'

Comment: Something that will help in the long run:https://realm.io/news/tryswift-novall-khan-swift-compiler-lldb/ and https://realm.io/news/tryswift-yuta-koshizawa-error-handling-swift/

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the stated question:**

Here's your error:

> Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent

The problem is in your `spawn_bullets()` function. You're not actually instantiating new bullets in this function. You're just updating properties on self's instance of bullet, then trying to add it as a child of your scene. The second time this function is called, it crashes, because the bullet is already a child of the scene.

Instead, you should create new instances of your bullet node.

**Regarding the underlying problem of creating unique bullets:**

This is a whole separate topic in and of itself. I assume you only want to fire bullets at specific times, such as when you tap on something, so rather than spawning bullets from the `update()` function, which is called before each frame is rendered, I would call `spawn_bullets()` from a tap method, or other interaction. Secondly, you will want to create new instances of your bullet instead of updating a variable on your scene. These can be added, animated, and subsequently removed. Finally, take a look at the `SKAction` class for actually animating (and ultimately removing) the bullets. For example:

```
let newBullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
newBullet.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
self.addChild(newBullet)

let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: 50, y: 10), duration: 0.4)
let removeAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()
newBullet.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveAction, removeAction])) {
    // Bullet is done and removed.
}
```

You can do a lot more with `SKAction` than is shown here. You can play audio files, follow paths, or even simply run a block.

Comment: Well, I am trying to make the hero shoot bullets. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *(surprised ...)* and this causes an *abort* signal?  Wow. (Mind you, Dalton, I **am not** disputing you!)

Answer (score 0):

It occurs on this line:

```
self.addChild(bullet)
```

This is because `bullet` already has a parent.

To fix it, add this line before you add the child:

```
bullet.removeFromParent()
```